# Unable to stop a windows service with net stop command

Tags: c++, winapi, service

I have created a windows service which is running fine by doing the following.

```
 SC_HANDLE hService = ::CreateService(*m_ServiceConfig,         // SCM database 
                                                name.c_str(),               // name of service 
                                                displayname.c_str(),        // service name to display 
                                                SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,         // desired access 

                                                SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS | SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS,    // service type (interactive for debug)

                                                SERVICE_AUTO_START,         // start type 
                                                SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,       // error control type 
                                                path.c_str(),               // path to service's binary 
                                                nullptr,                    // no load ordering group 
                                                nullptr,                    // no tag identifier 
                                                dependencies,               // dependencies 
                                                nullptr,                    // LocalSystem account 
                                                nullptr);                   // no password
```

As you can see i specified the access to be  `SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS` and online this constant states that you have access to pause continue and stop the service,

However when i run the command `net stop <service-name>` i get the following ouput

> the requested pause continue or stop is not valid for this service

my question is is there anything wrong with the way im creating the service?

Service Control Handler function

```
DWORD WINAPI ServiceControlHandler(DWORD dwControl, DWORD dwEventType, LPVOID /*lpEventData*/, LPVOID /*lpContext*/)
{
    // Handle the requested control code.

    switch (dwControl)
    {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
    TVLOG_INFO(L"SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP");
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Please stop the service", "Uninstall service error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

    }
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your [ServiceMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687414.aspx) or the [Control Handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687413.aspx) function.

Comment: @IInspectable I have added my control handler function at the moment im just working with the stop command

Comment: Please show how you are reporting service status to the SCM.  That affects how other apps, like `net`, can interact with your service.  Also, you cannot use `MessageBox()` in a service without specifying the `MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION` flag.

Answer (score 1):

The access rights you specify in the `dwDesiredAccess` parameter of `CreateService()` have no effect on the `net stop` command.  The access rights only apply to the returned `SC_HANDLE` and effect how that handle interacts with subsequent API calls.

The error you are seeing is most likely being caused by your calls to [`SetServiceStatus()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686241.aspx) not including the `SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP` flag in the `SERVICE_STATUS::dwControlsAccepted` field.

[SERVICE_STATUS structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685996.aspx)

> **dwControlsAccepted**
>   The control codes the service accepts and processes in its handler function (see [`Handler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683240.aspx) and [`HandlerEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683241.aspx)). A user interface process can control a service by specifying a control command in the [`ControlService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682108.aspx) or [`ControlServiceEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682110.aspx) function. By default, all services accept the **SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE** value. To accept the **SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT** value, the service must register to receive device events by using the [`RegisterDeviceNotification`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431.aspx) function.
>
> The following are the control codes.
>
> ...
>
> **SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP**
>   0x00000001
>
> The service can be stopped.
>
> This control code allows the service to receive **SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP** notifications.